# What ATI cards support split screen with OSS Linux drivers?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, fedora

I would like to have split screen, but I don't know which ATI card will fit my needs. It must be ATI, and it must work out of the box with the open source Linux drivers. My monitors have DVI-D connectors.

**Update:**

It is Fedora 14 I am going to install when I get the graphics card.

It is perfectly fine if I have to `yum install` to get the drivers, as long as it isn't the closed source drivers.

I thought it was called "split screen" when half the desktop is on each monitor, and moving the mouse across the edge of one of the monitors make it appear on the other monitor.

So it wasn't Crossfire I have in mind.

Comment: This is really a SuperUser.com question...

Comment: As per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq), no shopping questions are allowed.

Comment: When you say 'split screen' do you mean dual monitors or literally split screen (which requires running with two cards in Crossfire?)

Comment: Please ignore the buying advice and just answer what features the cards need to have to make it work. And let's hope Sandra comes back to follow up on @Shinrai's comment

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your wording what you mean by "split-screen", but I'm assuming you mean that you want a dual-screen display. Which Linux distro are you using? The drivers available "out of the box" will depend on what distro you're using. Do you need them to be on the install CD, or is it OK if they get downloaded automatically by the package manager?

Comment: is extended desktop (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-monitor) what you want? It used to be called xinerama: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any ATI card that has the necessary outputs should be able to do it, using the open source drivers and xrandr to configure the screens.

What you can't do using xrandr and open source drivers is to split the desktop across multiple monitors which are connected to different graphics cards, regardless of the make or model of the graphics cards.

Answer (score 1):

I have an ATI Radeon 4670 that runs multiple monitors fine on Fedora 14, but I use HDMI to connect one monitor (the other is DVI) since this particular card has 1 DVI and 1 HDMI port.

You can probably find a 4670 card with dual DVI ports instead. I am running the standard open drivers, and just configured the dual monitor support through the standard GNOME settings GUI.